# При компиляции возникает ошибка _CrtIsValidHeapPointer(block)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, указатели, дерево, компилятор

```
#include <cstdio>


struct node {


    int size;      // количество занятых ключей
    int key[3];
    node* first;   // *first <= key[0];
    node* second;  // key[0] <= *second < key[1];
    node* third;   // key[1] <= *third < key[2];
    node* fourth;  // kye[2] <= *fourth.
    node* parent; //Указатель на родителя нужен для того, потому что адрес корня может меняться при удалении

    bool find(int k) { // Этот метод возвращает true, если ключ k находится в вершине, иначе false.
        for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
            if (key[i] == k) return true;
        return false;
    }

    void swap(int& x, int& y) {
        int r = x;
        x = y;
        y = r;
    }

    void sort2(int& x, int& y) {
        if (x > y) swap(x, y);
    }

    void sort3(int& x, int& y, int& z) {
        if (x > y) swap(x, y);
        if (x > z) swap(x, z);
        if (y > z) swap(y, z);
    }

    void sort() { // Ключи в вершинах должны быть отсортированы
        if (size == 1) return;
        if (size == 2) sort2(key[0], key[1]);
        if (size == 3) sort3(key[0], key[1], key[2]);
    }

    void insert_to_node(int k) {  // Вставляем ключ k в вершину (не в дерево)
        key[size] = k;
        size++;
        sort();
    }

    void remove_from_node(int k) { // Удаляем ключ k из вершины (не из дерева)
        if (size >= 1 && key[0] == k) {
            key[0] = key[1];
            key[1] = key[2];
            size--;
        }
        else if (size == 2 && key[1] == k) {
            key[1] = key[2];
            size--;
        }
    }

    void become_node2(int k, node* first_, node* second_) {  // Преобразовать в 2-вершину.
        key[0] = k;
        first = first_;
        second = second_;
        third = nullptr;
        fourth = nullptr;
        parent = nullptr;
        size = 1;
    }

    bool is_leaf() { // Является ли узел листом; проверка используется при вставке и удалении.
        return (first == nullptr) && (second == nullptr) && (third == nullptr);
    }



    // Создавать всегда будем вершину только с одним ключом

    node(int k) : size(1), key{ k, 0, 0 }, first(nullptr), second(nullptr),
        third(nullptr), fourth(nullptr), parent(nullptr) {}

    node(int k, node* first_, node* second_, node* third_, node* fourth_, node* parent_) :
        size(1), key{ k, 0, 0 }, first(first_), second(second_),
        third(third_), fourth(fourth_), parent(parent_) {}

};



void printt(node* p);
node* merge(node* leaf);
node* redistribute(node* leaf);
node* fix(node* leaf);
node* remove(node* p, int k);
node* search_min(node* p);
node* search(node* p, int k);
node* split(node* item);
node* insert(node* p, int k);




node* insert(node* p, int k) { // вставка ключа k в дерево с корнем p; всегда возвращаем корень дерева, т.к. он может меняться
    if (!p) return new node(k); // если дерево пусто, то создаем первую 2-3-вершину (корень)

    if (p->is_leaf()) p->insert_to_node(k);
    else if (k <= p->key[0]) insert(p->first, k);
    else if ((p->size == 1) || ((p->size == 2) && k <= p->key[1])) insert(p->second, k);
    else insert(p->third, k);

    return split(p);
}


node* split(node* item) {
    if (item->size < 3) return item;

    node* x = new node(item->key[0], item->first, item->second, nullptr, nullptr, item->parent); // Создаем две новые вершины,
    node* y = new node(item->key[2], item->third, item->fourth, nullptr, nullptr, item->parent);  // которые имеют такого же родителя, как и разделяющийся элемент.
    if (x->first)  x->first->parent = x;    // Правильно устанавливаем "родителя" "сыновей".
    if (x->second) x->second->parent = x;   // После разделения, "родителем" "сыновей" является "дедушка",
    if (y->first)  y->first->parent = y;    // Поэтому нужно правильно установить указатели.
    if (y->second) y->second->parent = y;

    if (item->parent) {
        item->parent->insert_to_node(item->key[1]);

        if (item->parent->first == item) item->parent->first = nullptr;
        else if (item->parent->second == item) item->parent->second = nullptr;
        else if (item->parent->third == item) item->parent->third = nullptr;

        // Дальше происходит своеобразная сортировка ключей при разделении.
        if (item->parent->first == nullptr) {
            item->parent->fourth = item->parent->third;
            item->parent->third = item->parent->second;
            item->parent->second = y;
            item->parent->first = x;
        }
        else if (item->parent->second == nullptr) {
            item->parent->fourth = item->parent->third;
            item->parent->third = y;
            item->parent->second = x;
        }
        else {
            item->parent->fourth = y;
            item->parent->third = x;
        }

        node* tmp = item->parent;
        delete item;///
        return tmp;
    }
    else {
        x->parent = item;   // Так как в эту ветку попадает только корень,
        y->parent = item;   // то мы "родителем" новых вершин делаем разделяющийся элемент.
        item->become_node2(item->key[1], x, y);
        return item;
    }
}


node* search(node* p, int k) { // Поиск ключа k в 2-3 дереве с корнем p.
    if (!p) return nullptr;

    if (p->find(k)) return p;
    else if (k < p->key[0]) return search(p->first, k);
    else if ((p->size == 2) && (k < p->key[1]) || (p->size == 1)) return search(p->second, k);
    else if (p->size == 2) return search(p->third, k);
}


node* search_min(node* p) { // Поиск узла с минимальным элементов в 2-3-дереве с корнем p.
    if (!p) return p;
    if (!(p->first)) return p;
    else return search_min(p->first);
}


node* remove(node* p, int k) { // Удаление ключа k в 2-3-дереве с корнем p.
    node* item = search(p, k); // Ищем узел, где находится ключ k

    if (!item) return p;

    node* min = nullptr;
    if (item->key[0] == k) min = search_min(item->second); // Ищем эквивалентный ключ
    else min = search_min(item->third);

    if (min) { // Меняем ключи местами
        int& z = (k == item->key[0] ? item->key[0] : item->key[1]);
        item->swap(z, min->key[0]);
        item = min; // Перемещаем указатель на лист, т.к. min - всегда лист
    }

    item->remove_from_node(k); // И удаляем требуемый ключ из листа
    return fix(item); // Вызываем функцию для восстановления свойств дерева.
}


node* fix(node* leaf) {
    if (leaf->size == 0 && leaf->parent == nullptr) { // Случай 0, когда удаляем единственный ключ в дереве
        delete leaf;///
        return nullptr;
    }
    if (leaf->size != 0) { // Случай 1, когда вершина, в которой удалили ключ, имела два ключа
        if (leaf->parent) return fix(leaf->parent);
        else return leaf;
    }

    node* parent = leaf->parent;
    if (parent->first->size == 2 || parent->second->size == 2 || parent->size == 2) leaf = redistribute(leaf); // Случай 2, когда достаточно перераспределить ключи в дереве
    else if (parent->size == 2 && parent->third->size == 2) leaf = redistribute(leaf); // Аналогично
    else leaf = merge(leaf); // Случай 3, когда нужно произвести склеивание и пройтись вверх по дереву как минимум на еще одну вершину

    return fix(leaf);
}


node* redistribute(node* leaf) {
    node* parent = leaf->parent;
    node* first = parent->first;
    node* second = parent->second;
    node* third = parent->third;

    if ((parent->size == 2) && (first->size < 2) && (second->size < 2) && (third->size < 2)) {
        if (first == leaf) {
            parent->first = parent->second;
            parent->second = parent->third;
            parent->third = nullptr;
            parent->first->insert_to_node(parent->key[0]);
            parent->first->third = parent->first->second;
            parent->first->second = parent->first->first;

            if (leaf->first != nullptr) parent->first->first = leaf->first;
            else if (leaf->second != nullptr) parent->first->first = leaf->second;

            if (parent->first->first != nullptr) parent->first->first->parent = parent->first;

            parent->remove_from_node(parent->key[0]);
            delete first;///
        }
        else if (second == leaf) {
            first->insert_to_node(parent->key[0]);
            parent->remove_from_node(parent->key[0]);
            if (leaf->first != nullptr) first->third = leaf->first;
            else if (leaf->second != nullptr) first->third = leaf->second;

            if (first->third != nullptr) first->third->parent = first;

            parent->second = parent->third;
            parent->third = nullptr;

            delete second;///
        }
        else if (third == leaf) {
            second->insert_to_node(parent->key[1]);
            parent->third = nullptr;
            parent->remove_from_node(parent->key[1]);
            if (leaf->first != nullptr) second->third = leaf->first;
            else if (leaf->second != nullptr) second->third = leaf->second;

            if (second->third != nullptr)  second->third->parent = second;

            delete third;///
        }
    }
    else if ((parent->size == 2) && ((first->size == 2) || (second->size == 2) || (third->size == 2))) {
        if (third == leaf) {
            if (leaf->first != nullptr) {
                leaf->second = leaf->first;
                leaf->first = nullptr;
            }

            leaf->insert_to_node(parent->key[1]);
            if (second->size == 2) {
                parent->key[1] = second->key[1];
                second->remove_from_node(second->key[1]);
                leaf->first = second->third;
                second->third = nullptr;
                if (leaf->first != nullptr) leaf->first->parent = leaf;
            }
            else if (first->size == 2) {
                parent->key[1] = second->key[0];
                leaf->first = second->second;
                second->second = second->first;
                if (leaf->first != nullptr) leaf->first->parent = leaf;

                second->key[0] = parent->key[0];
                parent->key[0] = first->key[1];
                first->remove_from_node(first->key[1]);
                second->first = first->third;
                if (second->first != nullptr) second->first->parent = second;
                first->third = nullptr;
            }
        }
        else if (second == leaf) {
            if (third->size == 2) {
                if (leaf->first == nullptr) {
                    leaf->first = leaf->second;
                    leaf->second = nullptr;
                }
                second->insert_to_node(parent->key[1]);
                parent->key[1] = third->key[0];
                third->remove_from_node(third->key[0]);
                second->second = third->first;
                if (second->second != nullptr) second->second->parent = second;
                third->first = third->second;
                third->second = third->third;
                third->third = nullptr;
            }
            else if (first->size == 2) {
                if (leaf->second == nullptr) {
                    leaf->second = leaf->first;
                    leaf->first = nullptr;
                }
                second->insert_to_node(parent->key[0]);
                parent->key[0] = first->key[1];
                first->remove_from_node(first->key[1]);
                second->first = first->third;
                if (second->first != nullptr) second->first->parent = second;
                first->third = nullptr;
            }
        }
        else if (first == leaf) {
            if (leaf->first == nullptr) {
                leaf->first = leaf->second;
                leaf->second = nullptr;
            }
            first->insert_to_node(parent->key[0]);
            if (second->size == 2) {
                parent->key[0] = second->key[0];
                second->remove_from_node(second->key[0]);
                first->second = second->first;
                if (first->second != nullptr) first->second->parent = first;
                second->first = second->second;
                second->second = second->third;
                second->third = nullptr;
            }
            else if (third->size == 2) {
                parent->key[0] = second->key[0];
                second->key[0] = parent->key[1];
                parent->key[1] = third->key[0];
                third->remove_from_node(third->key[0]);
                first->second = second->first;
                if (first->second != nullptr) first->second->parent = first;
                second->first = second->second;
                second->second = third->first;
                if (second->second != nullptr) second->second->parent = second;
                third->first = third->second;
                third->second = third->third;
                third->third = nullptr;
            }
        }
    }
    else if (parent->size == 1) {
        leaf->insert_to_node(parent->key[0]);

        if (first == leaf && second->size == 2) {
            parent->key[0] = second->key[0];
            second->remove_from_node(second->key[0]);

            if (leaf->first == nullptr) leaf->first = leaf->second;

            leaf->second = second->first;
            second->first = second->second;
            second->second = second->third;
            second->third = nullptr;
            if (leaf->second != nullptr) leaf->second->parent = leaf;
        }
        else if (second == leaf && first->size == 2) {
            parent->key[0] = first->key[1];
            first->remove_from_node(first->key[1]);

            if (leaf->second == nullptr) leaf->second = leaf->first;

            leaf->first = first->third;
            first->third = nullptr;
            if (leaf->first != nullptr) leaf->first->parent = leaf;
        }
    }
    return parent;
}


node* merge(node* leaf) {
    node* parent = leaf->parent;

    if (parent->first == leaf) {
        parent->second->insert_to_node(parent->key[0]);
        parent->second->third = parent->second->second;
        parent->second->second = parent->second->first;

        if (leaf->first != nullptr) parent->second->first = leaf->first;
        else if (leaf->second != nullptr) parent->second->first = leaf->second;

        if (parent->second->first != nullptr) parent->second->first->parent = parent->second;

        parent->remove_from_node(parent->key[0]);
        delete parent->first;///
        parent->first = nullptr;
    }
    else if (parent->second == leaf) {
        parent->first->insert_to_node(parent->key[0]);

        if (leaf->first != nullptr) parent->first->third = leaf->first;
        else if (leaf->second != nullptr) parent->first->third = leaf->second;

        if (parent->first->third != nullptr) parent->first->third->parent = parent->first;

        parent->remove_from_node(parent->key[0]);
        delete parent->second;///
        parent->second = nullptr;
    }

    if (parent->parent == nullptr) {
        node* tmp = nullptr;
        if (parent->first != nullptr) tmp = parent->first;
        else tmp = parent->second;
        tmp->parent = nullptr;
        delete parent;///
        return tmp;
    }
    return parent;
}


void printt(node* p) {

    if (p != nullptr) {

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

            if (p->key[i] != 0)

                printf("%d\t", p->key[i]);
        }

        printt(p->first);
        printt(p->second);
        printt(p->third);

    }

}




int main() {


    node root(10);

    insert(&root, 20);
    insert(&root, 30);
    insert(&root, 40);
    insert(&root, 50);
    insert(&root, 60);
    insert(&root, 70);
    insert(&root, 80);
    insert(&root, 90);
    insert(&root, 100);
    insert(&root, 110);
    insert(&root, 120);
    insert(&root, 130);
    insert(&root, 140);
    insert(&root, 150);
    insert(&root, 5);
    insert(&root, 15);
    insert(&root, 25);
    insert(&root, 8);


    remove(&root, 5);
    remove(&root, 8);
    remove(&root, 10);
    remove(&root, 30);
    remove(&root, 15); //////ОШИБКА//////


    printt(&root);
    
}
```

При попытке скомпилировать код возникает ошибка при обработке `remove(&root, 15)`, а именно **_CrtIsValidHeapPointer(block)**

Возможно проблема в операции `delete`, которая удаляет узлы и отрабатывает в функциях: **merge()**, **fix()**, **split()**, **redistribute()**

Стандарт - ISO C++ 14

Comment: Так при компиляции или при выполнении? Все же, мне кажется, при выполнении. И еще. Понимаете, формально вы задали вопрос верный, но вот копаться в почти 500 строках кода вряд ли кто-то будет всерьез. Если сразу ошибку не обнаружит, то вряд ли будет искать ее, продираясь через такой код. Вам бы сделать минимальный пример, пробуя отключать какие-то функции, которые не влияют на это поведение, словом, выполнить хоть какую-то предварительную отладку самостоятельно.

Comment: debug Assertion failed окно, я так понимаю при компиляции. Все функции которые участвовали при процессе написаны под кодом, а так же подозрения на операцию ```delete```

Comment: Вообще-то при выполнении программы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В процессе отладки, заметил, что падает прога при удалении `node` в функции `merge` , `delete parent;` а адрес у него в стеке `0x7ff..`.
Так как вы не выделяли память для переменной `node root(10);` в функции `main` произошло падение проги из-за удаления неправильного указателя.
Помогает хранить этот объект не в стеке, а в куче.

```
node * rootp = new node(10);
```

И чтобы указатель автоматически менялся, его надо передавать ссылкой :

```
void merge(node* & leaf){
  ..
  delete parent ;
  leaf = tmp ;
  return ;
  ..
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, сделал хранение объекта в куче и поменял 3 строки в функции ```merge()```,  всё что вы написали в ответе, но теперь возникает проблема в функции **fix()**, а именно **leaf = nullptr** и не подлежит чтению :                                                                                                                               
` if (leaf->size == 0 && leaf->parent == nullptr) { 
        delete leaf;
        return nullptr;
    }`

Comment: ещё много работы переделок : вы игнорируете возвращаемые указатели от `insert` и `remove`. И по-этому нужно передавать и там аргумент указателя ссылкой. А в функции `fix()` пока-что проверяйте `leaf` на `nullptr` и выходите..

Comment: Я просто не понимаю, как у автора статьи с хабра этот код работал в том виде котором он был: https://habr.com/ru/post/303374/

Comment: читаем комментарий в `insert` : *"всегда возвращаем корень дерева, т.к. он может меняться"* и в этой-же функции просто вызывается `else insert(p->third, k);`. Загадочный комментарий с игнорированием нового указателя ветки `p->third`. Скорее всего код у него нерабочий. *Лучше просто самому учиться и писать **свой** код.*

Comment: Да, действительно, к сожалению на просторах интернета мало реализации 2-3 деревьев